# Angular2: Need to Instantiate Class to prevent Promise / Property not found error

Tags: typescript, angular, promise

In my "export class" if I don't do this:

```
purchase = new Purchase();
```

before my constructor, then I get a Promise error, that "name" is not found.

My HTML Template indeed binds to the class:

```
<h2 text-center><input [(ngModel)]="purchase.name"></h2>
```

But I expect this class to be provided by the Service Injector in the Constructor. Now that I have to tell my Detail Controller about the structure of the "purchase"-class I might run into problems when unit testing.

Any ideas how to avoid "purchase = new Purchase()" ?

Here's the full code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {PurchaseService} from '../../services/purchase.service';
import {Purchase} from '../../services/purchase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/detail/detail.html',
  providers: [PurchaseService] // teach injector how to make a PurchaseService
})

export class DetailPage implements OnInit{

  name: String;
  purchase = new Purchase();

  constructor(
    private _navController: NavController, 
    private _navParams: NavParams, 
    private purchaseService: PurchaseService) {

      this._navController = _navController;
      this.name = _navParams.get('name');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOnePurchase();
  }

  getOnePurchase() {
    this.purchaseService.getOnePurchase(name)
        .then(result => this.purchase = result
        )
        .then(result => console.log(result)
        )
  }

  pushPage(name: string) {
    this._navController.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `new Purchase()` and change your template to:

```
<h2 text-center><input [(ngModel)]="purchase?.name"></h2>
```